# Web scraping with beautiful soup only returns a small sample (not all the data)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I have a problem when using Beautifulsoup to get data from a page. The issue is when I apply my code, it is working well but is just returning only a sample of 33 products instead of the 82 that are in the page (all the 82 products has the same type of html organization). Hereunder the code and the html:

Python Code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.zalando.es/chaquetas-hombre/"

#Opening up connection, grabbing and closing after
uClient = uReq(url)
pagehtml = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page = BeautifulSoup(pagehtml, "html.parser")
resp = page.find_all("z-grid-item", {"class":"cat_card-1o_9G cat_normalWidth-tz8JR"})
print (len(resp))

tot_brand = list()
tot_products = list()
tot_prices = list()
tot_hiperlinks = list()

# Tomo los datos necesarios (Marca, precio, nombre, etc. etc.)
for i in resp:
    try:    
        brand = i.find("div", {"class": "cat_brandName-2XZRz cat_ellipsis-MujnT"}).text
        products = i.find("div", {"class": "cat_articleName--arFp cat_ellipsis-MujnT"}).text
        prices = i.find("div",{"class": "cat_originalPrice-2Oy4G"}).text[0:-2]
        prices = float(prices.replace(",","."))
        hlink = i.find("a").get("href")
```

I don't know if it is because I havent noticed something in any point or because maybe the page does not allow you to get all data you want. If any knows please let me know why?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see is on the page in Json form. You can use `json` module to parse it.

For example:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.zalando.es/chaquetas-hombre/'
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

json_data = json.loads(soup.select_one('#z-nvg-cognac-props').contents[0].replace('<![CDATA[', '').replace(']]>', ''))

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))

for no, article in enumerate(json_data['articles'], 1):
    print('{:<4}{:<25}{:<75}{}'.format(no, article['brand_name'], article['name'], article['url_key']))
```

Prints:

```
1   Ellesse                  LOMBARDY - Chaqueta de entretiempo - dress blues                           ellesse-chaqueta-de-invierno-dress-blues-el922l007-k11
2   Napapijri                SHELTER H  - Chaqueta fina - blu marine                                    napapijri-shelter-h-chaqueta-fina-blu-marine-na622t027-k11
3   SIKSILK                  DETACHABLE HOOD - Chaqueta vaquera - mid wash blue                         siksilk-detachable-hood-chaqueta-vaquera-mid-wash-blue-sif22t00j-k11
4   Jack & Jones             JCOROCKY - Chaqueta de cuero sintético - black                             jack-and-jones-jcorocky-jacket-chaqueta-de-cuero-sintetico-black-ja222t0b6-q11
5   New Look                 SLEEVE - Chaqueta vaquera - light blue                                     new-look-sleeve-chaqueta-vaquera-light-blue-nl022d07f-k11
6   Selected Homme           CLASSIC JACKET - Chaqueta de cuero - black                                 selected-homme-classic-jacket-chaqueta-de-cuero-black-se622t04e-q11
7   Jack & Jones             JJIALVIN JJJACKET - Chaqueta vaquera - blue denim                          jack-and-jones-jjialvin-jjjacket-chaqueta-vaquera-blue-denim-ja222t0c8-k11
8   Nike Sportswear          M NSW NIKE AIR JKT WVN - Cortaviento - white/black                         nike-sportswear-cortaviento-whiteblack-ni122t03x-a11
9   Only & Sons              ONSAL  - Chaqueta de cuero sintético - black                               only-and-sons-onsal-chaqueta-de-cuero-sintetico-black-os322t05c-q11
10  Ellesse                  MONTERINI PADDED - Cortaviento - black                                     ellesse-monterini-cortaviento-black-el922t026-q11
11  Oakwood                  CASEY  - Chaqueta de cuero - bordeaux                                      oakwood-casey-chaqueta-de-cuero-oa122j016-g11
12  Brave Soul               SANJAY - Chaquetas bomber - khaki                                          brave-soul-sanjay-chaquetas-bomber-brh22t01c-n11

...

80  Replay                   Chaqueta vaquera - dark blue                                               replay-chaqueta-vaquera-dark-blue-re322t01o-k11
81  Pier One                 Forro polar - dark green                                                   pier-one-forro-polar-dark-green-pi922s062-m11
82  CELIO                    RUALF - Chaquetas bomber - kaki                                            celio-rualf-chaquetas-bomber-cf522t01h-n11
83  Levi's®                  THE TRUCKER JACKET - Chaqueta vaquera - embossed 2 horse trucker           levisr-the-trucker-jacket-chaqueta-vaquera-embossed-2-horse-trucker-l1o22t002-k11
84  adidas Performance       VARILITE SOFT HOODED - Chaqueta de plumas - carbon                         adidas-performance-varilite-soft-chaqueta-de-plumas-carbon-ad542f0fb-q11
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andrej, it works perfectly now. I have to review and to study a bit the code cause I dont really know what is doing when you call the json.loads and what it is doing whit this soup.select_one('#z-nvg-cognac-props') neither with the bucle for. but thank you very much, really helpful